# Angular 2 identity method

Tags: angular

In AngularJS, we have [angular.identity](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.identity) which use to return the first argument.

But There is no such thing in Angular.

is there a different method in Angular which I can use?

Comment: i think you can create a custom method for the same

Comment: yeah, but I was wondering if there is a build in solution available in angular.

Comment: i think there is none no 100% though, you can check here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/

Comment: It's just `a => a`.

Comment: Angular doesn't provide such general tool functionality. Either TypeScript provides something or you can use a 3rd party TypeScript library that provides what you're looking for.